# Order arraylist based on multiple connection

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

This is my VO

```
public class SomeVO {

    private String name;        
    private String usageCount;
    private String numberofReturns;
    private String trendNumber;
    private String nonTrendNumber;
    private String trendType;
    private String auditType;
    public SomeVO(String name,String usageCount,String numberofReturns,String trendNumber,String nonTrendNumber,String trendType,String auditType){
        this.name = name;
        this.usageCount = usageCount;
        this.numberofReturns = numberofReturns;
        this.trendNumber = trendNumber;
        this.nonTrendNumber = nonTrendNumber;
        this.trendType = trendType;
        this.auditType = auditType;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUsageCount() {
        return usageCount;
    }
    public void setUsageCount(String usageCount) {
        this.usageCount = usageCount;
    }
    public String getNumberofReturns() {
        return numberofReturns;
    }
    public void setNumberofReturns(String numberofReturns) {
        this.numberofReturns = numberofReturns;
    }
    public String getTrendNumber() {
        return trendNumber;
    }
    public void setTrendNumber(String trendNumber) {
        this.trendNumber = trendNumber;
    }
    public String getNonTrendNumber() {
        return nonTrendNumber;
    }
    public void setNonTrendNumber(String nonTrendNumber) {
        this.nonTrendNumber = nonTrendNumber;
    }
    public String getTrendType() {
        return trendType;
    }
    public void setTrendType(String trendType) {
        this.trendType = trendType;
    }
    public String getAuditType() {
        return auditType;
    }
    public void setAuditType(String auditType) {
        this.auditType = auditType;
    }
}
```

Here is my values

```
List<SomeVO> myList = new ArrayList<SomeVO>();
        SomeVO some = new SomeVO("A","0","0","123","123","Trend","AuditX");
        myList.add(some);
        some = new SomeVO("B","1","1","234","234","Non trend","AuditX");
        myList.add(some);
        some = new SomeVO("C","0","2","345","345","Trend","AuditX");
        myList.add(some);
        some = new SomeVO("D","2","3","546","546","Trend","AuditX");
        myList.add(some);
        some = new SomeVO("E","2","4","678","678","Non trend","AuditX");
        myList.add(some);
        some = new SomeVO("F","0","0","123","123","Non trend","AuditA");
        myList.add(some);
        some = new SomeVO("G","0","0","123","123","Trend","AuditB");
        myList.add(some);
```

Here is my comparator

```
public String currentAudit = "AuditX";
public class AuditComparator implements Comparator<SomeVO> {

        @Override
        public int compare(SomeVO o1, SomeVO o2) {
            if(currentAudit.equalsIgnoreCase(o1.getAuditType()) && currentAudit.equalsIgnoreCase(o2.getAuditType())) {
                int value1 = o2.getUsageCount().compareTo(o1.getUsageCount());
                if (value1 == 0) {
                    int value2 = o1.getNumberofReturns().compareTo(o2.getNumberofReturns());
                    if(o1.getTrendType().equalsIgnoreCase("Trend") && o2.getTrendType().equalsIgnoreCase("Trend")) {
                        if (value2 == 0) {
                            return o1.getTrendNumber().compareTo(o2.getTrendNumber());
                        } else {
                            return value2;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (value2 == 0) {
                            return o1.getNonTrendNumber().compareTo(o2.getNonTrendNumber());
                        } else {
                            return value2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return value1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }

        }
    }
```

I am trying to sort the VO based on below conditions

1. First only set of values of currentAudit should be taken in to
   consideration i.e., AuditX

   a) then it should be sorted with
       Usage count in descending order

   b) if same usage count found then it
       should be sorted with Return count in ascending order

   c) if same
       return count then it should check for trendType, if trendType
       ="Trend" then it should sort with Trend number otherwise nonTrend number.
2. then it should consider rest all auditType's and sorted with
   a),b),c) condition as like currentAudit.  I tried achieving it and i
   ended up with only above comparator.  Expected result: D, A, C, E,
   F, G. But i get G,F,D,E,B,A,C. Please help me to update the
   comparator above.

Comment: First guess: you are comparing numbers as strings, I would suggest to convert those strings into numbers. Any way you are testing seven list items: it should not be difficult to debug (with breakpoints) and see where the comparator "fails".

Comment: Your expectation is wrong at the first glance D and the E afterwards is a correct sort

Comment: When both `A.auditType` and `B.auditType` are equal to `"AuditX"`, then `compare(A, B) == compare(B, A) == 1`. It is violation of comparator's rules.

Comment: There is something strange in `if(currentAudit.equalsIgnoreCase(o1.getAuditType()))`: you are comparing o1 but you are not checking o2.

Comment: @Sercan Ozdemir, Condition here is first Trend, then Nontrend of Audit X, So D, A,C,E,F,G.

Comment: @Giuseppe Marra added that condition in above question.

Comment: You have to consideer all the possibilities of o1 and o2 related to the auditType. It's ok when they are both equals to currentAudit. Now you have to give the rule for o1=currentAudit but not o2, o2=currentAudit but not o1, both different from currentAudit. Otherwise as @saka1029 said, you are violating the comparation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by splitting the actual list in to 2 list based on AuditX and rest in another list. Then used below comparator one by one, and then merged in to a result list. Works good.

```
for(SomeVO some:myList) {
            if(some.getAuditType().equalsIgnoreCase("AuditX")) {
                auditX.add(some);
            } else {
                auditY.add(some);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(auditX, new AuditComparator());            
        Collections.sort(auditY, new AuditComparator());

    public class AuditComparator implements Comparator<SomeVO> {

            @Override
            public int compare(SomeVO o1, SomeVO o2) {
                int value1 = o2.getUsageCount().compareTo(o1.getUsageCount());
                 if (value1 == 0) {
                        int value2 = o1.getNumberofReturns().compareTo(o2.getNumberofReturns());
                        if (value2 == 0) {
                            return (o1.getTrendType().equalsIgnoreCase("Trend") && o2.getTrendType().equalsIgnoreCase("Trend")) ?
                                    o1.getTrendNumber().compareTo(o2.getTrendNumber()):o1.getNonTrendNumber().compareTo(o2.getNonTrendNumber());
                        } else {
                            return value2;
                        }            
            }
                return value1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator does not meet a simple condition: it is not stateless. A following should always be true: `A>B => B<A`. In your case, in some scenarios `A>B and B>A`.

Answer (score 0):

The return 1 at the bottom of the comparator makes a bug.
The comparator shall only return 1 if the second element is bigger than the first one, but if they're different, you always return 1, so the very first sorting criteria will be messy.

```
   // a helper for case insensitive comparison
   private int compareIgnoreCase(String o1,String o2) {
       return o1.toLowercase.compareTo(o2.toLowercase());
   }

   @Override
    public int compare(SomeVO o1, SomeVO o2) {
        int result=compareIgnoreCase(o1.getAuditType(),o2.getAuditType());
        if (result==0) {
            // we need to go to the 2nd criteria
            result=o2.getUsageCount().compareTo(o1.getUsageCount());
        }
        if (result==0) {
            // ok, 1st and 2nd criteria was the same, go to the 3rd             
          result=o1.getNumberofReturns().compareTo(o2.getNumberofReturns());
        }
        if (result==0) {
            // check trends
            ...
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I found that this representation of multiple comparison criteria makes the code much easier to follow. We first do the highest priority of comparison, and go on with further comparions if the previous comparisons returned that the two elements are the same (i.e. result is still zero).

In case you need to make a descending sorting at some level, simply put a -, e.g.:

```
 result=-o1.something.compareTo(o2.something)
```

It is a good idea to have only one exit point in a method (this also makes easier to follow what is happening).